# Pandas GUI like tool for Web Applications for making charts from Python Data frame without coding

Tags: python, pandas, web-deployment, pandasgui

I am looking for a GUI tool that can be deployed through a web application to end users. Users should be able to create charts from the given Pandas Data frame as per their requirements using point and click methods without coding.

I came across [Pandas-GUI](https://pypi.org/project/pandasgui) that matches my requirements but I am not sure if it can be served to other users through a web application. Is there any similar packages available for web platforms?

My Application is created using Django Framework and Data frame is generated in the application backend. My users neither have python installed on their computers, nor know how to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is 2 months old question but anyways. I was also looking for something similar and I found this great library: [dtale](https://pypi.org/project/dtale/). This can be used from a jupyter notebook as well as you can run it via flask application like this (Credits to @Micho.bojcevski for [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68484077/10183880)):

```
from flask import redirect

from dtale.app import build_app
from dtale.views import startup
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = build_app(reaper_on=False)

    @app.route("/create-df")
    def create_df():
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6]))
        instance = startup(data=df, ignore_duplicate=True)
        return redirect(f"/dtale/main/{instance._data_id}", code=302)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hi there, load data using <a href="/create-df">create-df</a>'

    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

The only thing that is missing for me was to add my own functions to the user interface. I wanted to allow users to make changes to the dataframe and apply my custom functions to the dataframe.